# Reference variable tables using dynamic table names - Power BI, DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a measure whereby I calculate some data based on a slicer value. The slicer determines which table I get my data from e.g. `SUM(TableA[sales])` or `SUM(TableB[sales])`. (Each of my tables is of the same structure).

I'd like to be able to set up a variable to dynamically change (with my slicer) which table I'm referring to.

Right now I have:

```
// Set __table to a stored string representation of the name of the database
// This seems to work
VAR __table = SELECTEDVALUE( AllTables[TableNames] )

// Evaluate the sales column of my variable table
// This doesn't work due to 'Cannot find name sales'
CALCULATE(SUM(__table[sales]))
```

I guess what I'm after is a way to have the slicer change the referenced table in my measures (with all of the columns being the same for each table).

I'm new to Power BI and I've been struggling with this for several days now. I'd really appreciate any help with either the method I'm attempting or any alternatives.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do exactly what you're after but you don't usually *need* to do this with a good model. Why do you need to switch among tables and approximately how many tables are you trying to switch between?

Comment: @AlexisOlson Hi, could be up to about 20 tables. It's for data gathered from devices in different places around an office, where each device is imported as its own table. The user can then switch between seeing the data from the different data tables on their views by using a slicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have small amount of data in each table, you can merge them all together as they are in same structure. Just add an additional column with reference of the Table name. Now you can create your Slicer using the new column and it will hold all table names in the list. Now, if you change table name in the slicer, your visuals will show results based on data from that respected table.

Comment: In case the original tables shall work as just now then a view with an extra source table column with UNION ALL between all the tables adds a more dynamic layer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. Would this work for larger tables (20000+ records added per day) or would I have issues?

Comment: unless you have millions of records all together, there is no issue. For your case, you can also think about period like last 12 or 36 month's data to be added in the new table. This depends on your requirement. But you can remove older data that never shown in the visual.

Comment: I'll attempt doing it this way. Thank you for your help.